# Accessing files inside folders in a zipfile

Tags: python, xml, xslt, python-zipfile

I would like to access files(xml files) in a zip file in order to do some filtering on them. But how can I go far into the folders in the zip file to access files? My problem is that I can not access files by zip_file.namelist If they are in some folders, here is my code:

```
import sys, getopt
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
import zipfile

def main(argv):

    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
       print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
       sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
       if opt == '-h':
          print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
          sys.exit()
       elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
          inputfile = arg
       elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
          outputfile = arg

    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(inputfile, 'r')

    with archive as zip_file:
      for file in zip_file.namelist():
          if file.endswith(".amd"):
              try:

                  print("Process the file")
                  xslt_root = etree.XML('''\
                    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

                    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
                      <xsl:copy>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                      </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:template>


                    <xsl:template match="TimeStamp"/>
                    <xsl:template match="@timeStamp"/>
                    <xsl:template match="TimeStamps"/>
                    <xsl:template match="Signature"/>

                    </xsl:stylesheet>
                    ''')

                  transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)

                  doc = etree.parse(zip_file.open(file))
                  result_tree = transform(doc)

                  resultfile = unicode(str(result_tree))
                  zip_file.write(resultfile)


              finally:
                  zip_file.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
     main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Exception: It can not read "ex4_linktime/" as this is a folder and not a file!

```
 File "parser.pxi", line 1110, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile     (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:96832)
 File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:91290)
 File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:92476)
 File "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:91737)
 IOError: Error reading file 'ex4_linktime/': failed to load external entity "ex4_linktime/"
```

Exception 2: It does not write back the changed file!

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1033, in write
    st = os.stat(filename)
WindowsErrorProcess the file
: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: u'<?xml version="1.0"?   >\n<ComponentData toolVersion="V6.1.4" schemaVersion="6.1.0.0">\n\t<DataSet name="Bank1">...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When you do `etree.parse(file)`, file is just a string. etree doesn't know that it has to go search in the zip file for that name, it will just look in the current directory. Try:

  ```
  doc = etree.parse(zip_file.open(file))
  ```
- You also have to skip over directory names -- these will have a trailing slash:

  ```
  for filename in zip_file.namelist():
      if filename.endswith('/'):
          # skip directory names
          continue
  ```
- To update the zip file, use:

  ```
  zip_file.writestr(filename, resultfile)
  ```

Comment: Tnx, this solved my problem. But now I have another exception. I have updated the question with your solution and also added the new exception.

Comment: @OrclUser, use `zip_file.writestr(filename, resultfile)`.

Comment: raises this exception:    raise RuntimeError, 'write() requires mode "w" or "a"'
RuntimeError: write() requires mode "w" or "a"

Comment: when I open it with 'w', I end up with an empty zipfile!

Comment: @OrclUser, actually I'm not sure if the zipfile module can replace files in a zip file. It's probably safest to create a new output zip file.

Comment: I would rather keep the zip file and write the updated one to a new zip named by "outputfile" which I get as input argument.